# Parallel Web Service Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I need to access 10-15 web-services simultaneously in ASP.NET MVC. Some of these services return JSON while others return XML.
What would be the best practice for this ?Would Tasks.parallel solve purpose ?
Points in consideration :

1. Number on concurrent users.
2. Faster response time to end user.
3. Lower load on server.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a number of ways, but perhaps using async web requests would be simpler to write. See my answer here for details. [MVC3 Passing ControllerContext to thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471746/mvc3-passing-controllercontext-to-thread/22262367#22262367)

Make an action for each service that you need to call